# How to verify the string value from a richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, text, richtextbox

Original Code:

The code below always runs `Case Else` because the text values have an exclamation in them. It I were to remove them, then they would work again.

```
Private Sub CommandLineFunctions()
    Select Case True
        Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text = "!exit"
            ToolStripButtonClose.PerformClick()
        Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text = "!clear"
            MessageDisplayBounds.Text = String.Empty
        Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text = "!disable"
            DeveloperMode.Enabled = False
            CloseForm(ToolStripButtonClose, EventArgs.Empty)
        Case Else
            MessageDisplayBounds.Text += DeveloperCommandLine.Text & vbCr
            ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Value = ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Maximum
    End Select
    DeveloperCommandLine.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**

Trying the suggested method (seen below) also only runs `Case Else`.

```
Private Sub CommandLineFunctions()
    Select Case True
        Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text.Equals("!exit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            ToolStripButtonClose.PerformClick()
        Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text.Equals("!clear", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            MessageDisplayBounds.Text = String.Empty
        Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text.Equals("!disable", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            DeveloperMode.Enabled = False
            CloseForm(ToolStripButtonClose, EventArgs.Empty)
        Case Else
            MessageDisplayBounds.Text += DeveloperCommandLine.Text & vbCr
            ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Value = ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Maximum
    End Select
    DeveloperCommandLine.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to check if the string matches in every way other than case sensitivity. If I have to do a case sensitive validating method then that is find cause I will just `ToLower` to get around it.

Comment: If you want a case insensitive match, you can keep the current form and change in, e.g., `[...] Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text.Equals("!exit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) [...]` -- I don't know what *check if the string matches in every way other than case sensitivity* means, in practice. You'll have to add - to the question, not in comments - a better description of your intentions.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how else to explain that. I am pretty new to programming and I am self taught so it is hard for me to explain some things well. I'll just vote delete the post because this has just become problematic than its worth. Unfortunately, `Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text.Equals("!exit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` did not work either. Thank you for your help though. I will try explaining things better in my future questions.

Comment: If you want to test whether the Text **contains** a string, you can use, e.g., `Case DeveloperCommandLine.Text.IndexOf("!exit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Comment: Just a question, you are trying to match on "!exit", that explanation mark isn't supposed to be doing some logic negation? For example DeveloperCommandLine.Text Not Equal to exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by looping through all `Char`'s in the string. Apparently `Environment.NewLine`, `vbcr`, or something similar gets added to the end of the string. To resolve this I used the following code:

```vb
    Private Sub CommandLineFunctions()
        Dim GetChars As New List(Of String)
        For Each i As Char In DeveloperCommandLine.Text
            GetChars.Add(i)
        Next
        GetChars.Remove(GetChars.Last)
        Dim CleanInput As String = String.Join("", GetChars)
        Select Case True
            Case CleanInput = "!exit"
                ToolStripButtonClose.PerformClick()
            Case CleanInput = "!clear"
                MessageDisplayBounds.Text = String.Empty
            Case CleanInput = "!disable"
                DeveloperMode.Enabled = False
                CloseForm(ToolStripButtonClose, EventArgs.Empty)
            Case Else
                MessageDisplayBounds.Text += DeveloperCommandLine.Text & vbCr
                ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Value = ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Maximum
        End Select
        DeveloperCommandLine.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the Select Case:

```
    If DeveloperCommandLine.Text.ToLower().Contains("exit") Then
        ToolStripButtonClose.PerformClick()
    ElseIf DeveloperCommandLine.Text.ToLower().Contains("clear") Then
        MessageDisplayBounds.Text = String.Empty
    ElseIf DeveloperCommandLine.Text.ToLower().Contains("disable") Then
        DeveloperMode.Enabled = False
        CloseForm(ToolStripButtonClose, EventArgs.Empty)
    Else
        MessageDisplayBounds.Text += DeveloperCommandLine.Text & vbCr
        ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Value = ScrollableContentCollection.VerticalScroll.Maximum
    End If
```

Comment: This works, but it, naturally, will work even if they are just substrings of the text.